How do I use a "not in list" type query for multiple columns in Kotlin Exposed?
I'm trying to do a query like the following:
DELETE FROM table 
  WHERE foreignKeyIdColumn = "foreignKeyIdValue" 
  AND (column1, column2) NOT IN (("value1", "value2"), ("value3", "value4"));

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it short of passing in raw SQL. The tables in question have a composite PK consisting of FKs to other tables.

Sample.deleteWhere { 
    (Sample.foreignKeyIdValue eq "foreignKeyIdValue")
    .and(Sample.column1 notInList listOf("value1", "value2"))
    .and(Sample.column2 notInList listOf("value3", "value4")) 
}


This answer could be improved by adding an explanation.
